# FTP settings working on mobile internet, but not my wifi

Tags: ftp

i can connect to my ftp server when i share my mobile connection. but on my home wifi i cannot.

if i do a **telnet domain:21**
i get a **220 microsoft ftp** message, and after some time is says "no connection"

I can ping the server so its either my ISP or my router. and i've now tried for hours and i still cannot get the connection right.

I have a Netgear Nighthawk X4 R7500 router and i added the default FTP options in the port forwarding settings.

Im really frustrated by now and im open for any suggestions xD

I also have teamviewer if anyone could look at my router config.

Comment: Is your FTP server also on your home network?

Comment: Are you hosting the FTP server yourself on your local network?

Comment: [Network administration](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and troubleshooting is really off-topic for this site. Questions here are required to be about [websites under your control](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). You might be able to ask this over at [Super User](http://superuser.com/), but be sure to check the FAQ in their Help Center first, and you should likely remove the last sentence as you certainly don't want just anyone looking at your router configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the connection into passive mode and see if you can get any further. Filezilla enables you to do this.

Comment: Why would this work?   Do you have experience with it?   Can you link to any documentation?